Show non-truncated usernames of users connected to sshd server in terminal?
On my Ubuntu server, I find it very useful that netstat -tulpn also shows the username connected to sshd (apparently, this username printing is specifically for sshd) - unfortunately, this printout is also truncated:
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 'PID\|user1'
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:12345           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1620557/sshd: user1
tcp6       0      0 :::12345                :::*                    LISTEN      1620557/sshd: user1

In the above example, full username is user1234, but due to truncation, I can only read user1.
Even more unfortunately, I learned that this truncation is hardcoded in netcat in Netstat output line width limit :

Unfortunately the width of the PID/Program name column in netstat is hardcoded with #define PROGNAME_WIDTH 20 so there is no way of getting the full output from netstat directly. Also you end up with 19 characters and a space at the end.

The same answer also recommends:

In today's linux one can use sudo ss -natp to get the full info formatted a bit differently but with the full name:

... unfortunately, ss does not print the username of the user connected to sshd as netstat does:
$ sudo ss -tulpn | grep user1
$

$ sudo ss -tulpn | grep 12345
tcp     LISTEN   0        128              0.0.0.0:12345          0.0.0.0:*      users:(("sshd",pid=1620557,fd=10))

tcp     LISTEN   0        128                 [::]:12345             [::]:*      users:(("sshd",pid=1620557,fd=11))

So, how can I get an output identical or similar to the output of netstat -tulpn, but which prints the full usernames connected to sshd?
My netstat version is:
$ netstat --version
net-tools 2.10-alpha
Fred Baumgarten, Alan Cox, Bernd Eckenfels, Phil Blundell, Tuan Hoang, Brian Micek and others
+NEW_ADDRT +RTF_IRTT +RTF_REJECT +FW_MASQUERADE +I18N +SELINUX
AF: (inet) +UNIX +INET +INET6 +IPX +AX25 +NETROM +X25 +ATALK +ECONET +ROSE -BLUETOOTH
HW:  +ETHER +ARC +SLIP +PPP +TUNNEL -TR +AX25 +NETROM +X25 +FR +ROSE +ASH +SIT +FDDI +HIPPI +HDLC/LAPB +EUI64



ss does not print the username of the user connected to sshd as netstat does

netstat doesn't do that, either! It just prints the cmdline of that process. No guarantees that the user that's authenticating is the same as the user running something; that's up to how things are configured.
Anyways, to get the executing user:
I'd simply write a script that, to each line of output, looks for pid=([0-9][0-9]*),, thus extracting the process ID from the line, then goes and gets the owner of /proc/{pid} , e.g. by doing stat -c '%U' "/proc/{pid}", and appends that to the line.
Generally, seems a pretty bad idea to get the list of SSH-logged-in-users via netstat. loginctl list-sessions would give you a list of sessions (becuase Ubuntu uses logind/systemd)
